# Count highest no of conversation between two clients

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I have a table called email with three columns say id, emailFrom, emailTo

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | emailFrom        | EmailT0                |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  | A                | B                      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  | B                | A                      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 3  | A                | B                      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 4  | C                | A                      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 5  | B                | C                      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 6  | A                | C                      |
--------------------------------------------------
| 7  | A                | B                      |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**now my question is , how to find out the highest conversation between two clients**

*i.e. A send mail to B and B send mail to A, it means they have conversation of count 2.
now,*
**I want to find that which users have send most emails to each other**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return the users that have sent most emails to each other:

```
SELECT
  LEAST(emailFrom, emailTo) email1,
  GREATEST(emailFrom, emailTo) email2,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  yourtable
GROUP BY
  LEAST(emailFrom, emailTo),
  GREATEST(emailFrom, emailTo)
ORDER BY
  COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56535f/1).

Comment: @user2531799 you're welcome :) you don't have to, but pls don't forget to accept the answer if you wish... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work tnx!

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward COUNT(*) with a GROUP BY will do it:

```
select emailFrom, emailTo, count(*) as conversation_count
from email
group by emailFrom, emailTo;
```

Comment: That will only count emails going one direction, not both ways.

Comment: Ah misread it being it bidirectional, @fthiella answered in that case ;)

Comment: This will not tell you what is being asked, I have already tried this query and only after this I have posted my question here, the above query will do the trick ...